# How to get the different URL for action methods in single controller without controller name in URL?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am working on a simple MVC website. In my project there is only one controller (`Home`) and 2 action methods in it (`Index` and `Inner` pages). `Home` action returns the view for home page and the `Inner` pages action returns the content for inner pages (inner pages uses the single template, so use the single view for all inner pages).

Now all I want is, if I run the project I got the menus like:

```
http://localhost:3000/Home/
http://localhost:3000/Home/Info/AboutUs
http://localhost:3000/Home/Info/Contact
```

But instead of above path I need paths like:

```
http://localhost:3000/Home/
http://localhost:3000/AboutUs
http://localhost:3000/Contact
```

without adding new controller and the url needs to call their corresponding action methods.

My routing file is

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

Could you please help me to achieve this?

Comment: Sure the actions on the `HomeController` aren't `Index` and `Info`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a custom route to your routes table. But make sure you also keep the default route. For example, I've create below a custom route named "HomeRoute" while keeping the default one...

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "HomeRoute",
            url: "{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

But, be aware that you need to define the action methods in the home controller since the default controller is set to "Home", if they are defined in a different controller then change the default controller

In other words, if your Home controller is defined as follows...

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(){...}
    public ActionResult About(){...}
}
```

Then you can navigate to the `About` action with the following route...

sitename/About